# Validation Failed On Windows Failover Cluster Access Denied

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, failover, failovercluster

i have 2 node will be setup windows failover cluster.
every node already connect to Active Directory.
when i validate on windows failover cluster, still failed on List Disk

error message like this
[image]

Comment: Do you have shared storage for your cluster? You should have shared storage in order to  pash this test. You can try using either S2D or StarWind VSAN as a shared storage to create a 2 node cluster. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/nested-resiliency#:~:text=Nested%20resiliency%20is%20a%20new,continue%20to%20run%20without%20disruption.

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/starwind-virtual-san-for-hyper-v-2-node-hyperconverged-scenario-with-windows-server-2016/

Comment: Previously my current AD using zentyal.  but after that I install Windows AD. is successfully.

but this impact from zentyal ?

Comment: Failover clustering is not listed as a supported feature of zentyal. So, it could be related to it. https://zentyal.com/features/#domain